# What is the meaning of "rather"?

Tags: british-english

> It is rather a nuisance.
>
> It is a rather nuisance.

Which sentence is correct, and what is the meaning of rather here?

Answer (score 3):

This is from [MW-D definition #5](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather) of 'rather'.

> 5: in some degree : SOMEWHAT
>
> e.g. *it's rather warm*
>
> —often used as a mild intensive
>
> e.g. *spent rather a lot of money*

The correct sentence is: *It is rather a nuisance.* 'Rather' is an adverb modifying 'is' and positioned after it. It cannot be placed between 'a' and 'nuisance' as only something being used as an adjective could appear within a noun phrase like that.

Comment: With all repsect to the MW-D I think it misses the nuisances of the way rather in Britsh English.https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rather Rather can mean a significant amount not just a mild amount in British English.